# Dealing with large arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Okay a couple of simple questions.

First, am I correct to assume that doing this is a bad idea because the array gets recreated each time the function is called?

```
function foo(){
    $arr = {"REALLY_BIG_ARRAY":"HAS LIKE 1000 ELEMENTS"}; 
}
```

Now to deal with this I came up with the idea of doing this:

```
class example {
    public static $property =  {"REALLY_BIG_ARRAY":"HAS LIKE 1000 ELEMENTS"};
}

function foo(){
    //to use the array I do
    foo::$property["some_element"]; //Do something with this 
}
```

I am using this in a small web app I am currently building. Are there any good ways of dealing with big data arrays in PHP. This function gets called a lot so thats why putting the array in DV seemed like a bad idea.

Comment: Are you going to need all 1000 every time you load ... is there a way to lazy load only the values that you need? What do you have to do to get at the 1000 elements... maybe some kind of cache could be utilized.

Comment: You don't need to hardcode your data in PHP. Just use data store like Memcache or Redis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static variable:

```
function foo(){
    static $arr = {"REALLY_BIG_ARRAY":"HAS LIKE 1000 ELEMENTS"}; 
}
```

It will only be created the first time you call the function, future calls will reuse the value.